# File cannot be validated as the XML Definition, How to fix faces-config.xml warning?

Tags: jsf, eclipse-plugin, xpages, lotus-domino, domino-designer-eclipse

Lately when I bring up my on-server Working Set in Domino Designer (Release 9.0.1FP10 SHF68), I've been met with new error and warning messages.

> The file cannot be validated as the XML definition
>   "C:\Notes\Data\workspace\myserver\dev_5csandbox.nsf\WebContent\WEB-INF\faces-config.xml
>   (The system cannot find the path specified.)" that is specified as
>   describing the syntax of the file cannot be located.

I look at the Faces-config and see this:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><faces-config>
  <!--AUTOGEN-START-BUILDER: Automatically generated by IBM Domino Designer. Do not modify.-->
  <!--AUTOGEN-END-BUILDER: End of automatically generated section-->
</faces-config>
```

with a yellow exclamation warning icon beside line 1.  Location unknown.

I know it's an **XML Problem** warning but there's an error saying

> "META-INF/MANIFEST.MF does not exist"

that comes and disappears beforehand, along with a slew of 10 warnings to do with it.

> Eclipse-LazyStart header is deprecated, use 'Bundle-ActivationPolicy'

also show up.  All except one, are **Plug-in Problem** types (Resource: plugin.xml)

I'm not sure what to do about this, can someone shed a little light on this and point me in the right direction?

[image]

Comment: Regarding the jsf validation error, there is no xsd/dtd definition in there so it cannot be validated. Look at how normal faces-config.xml files are defined.

Comment: Perhaps a re-install of Domino Designer is needed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**@Per Henrik Lausten** had the right idea: **Reinstall**.  So I did and upgraded to SHF252 while I was at it.

No more mysterious Manifest errors.